# Does logback have a NullAppender?

Tags: java, logging, logback

I know there is a `NullAppender` in log4j. But I can't find the appender in logback. Is there a better way for ignoring all logs in logback?

Comment: This question is clearly not a duplicate. Filtering out is completely different from having the ability to specify a null appender.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting the log level to `OFF` will ignore all logs.

```
<logger name="..." level="OFF" />
```

Comment: +1.  Can you add some more detail to your answer to show an example.  Maybe something like:   `<logger name="org.eclipse.jetty" level="OFF" />`

Comment: But you must fill the "name" attribute in <logger> tag and that will limit the log which "level=off" is applied.

Answer (score 18):

This is an old question, but the answers already given do not actually answer it.

**Yes**

There is a "null" appender, but that is not what it is called. I believe the logback author prefers the term "no-op" when referring to implementations that exist to satisfy some compile, test, or other design requirements, but do not actually perform any operation. The appender implementation that was originally asked about is:

```
ch.qos.logback.core.helpers.NOPAppender
```

[javadoc](https://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/helpers/NOPAppender.html)

[source](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/helpers/NOPAppender.java)

Answer (score 4):

Just curious, what is the point using a NullAppender (which I believe is an Appender that do nothing) while you can simply **not setting** any appender to a logger?

And, the proper way to turn off all log is by setting the log level to OFF.

---

With comment from @djechlin, I believe it is also worth mentioning Filters in LogBack.  If you simply want to turn off all messages going through an appender, you can simply make use of Threshold Filter:

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- Deny everything below OFF, that means deny everything -->
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>OFF</level>
    </filter>
    .... other config
</appender>
```

Comment: I have many pkgs in the project and they share the same ROOT config. And somehow I wanna ignore all logs for classes in pkg1 only.

Comment: Then simply set the log level of pkg1 to OFF.  That's one of the main purpose of using log4j-like logging library: you can control the behavior of individual logger (and its child).  If you have a null appender, you will still need to configure your log4j to set logger pkg1 to use the null appender and set its additivity to false, for which is simply the same place you set the log level for pkg1.

Comment: Many loggers that require one appender that should be disabled depending on configuration (say dev/prod). To make a DRY change the appender needs to be nulled out.

Comment: @djechlin probably there are situation that is appropriate.  However  given most, if not all, built-in appender in Logback do provide support for Filter, what you are looking for can be easily done by putting a Threshold filter and set the threshold to OFF.  This even make the configuration more reusable (and more DRY) across different env.

Comment: I used the Log4J null appender to have a Hibernate-specific logger with a level of WARN. That filtered out the voluminous messages Hibernate generates without doing any output. The WARN Hibernate messages were then passed to the root logger for normal output.

Comment: @Steve11235 What's the difference of simply setting the Hibernate logger with WARN level then?

Answer (score 4):

You can always write one:

```
public class NullAppender extends UnsynchronizedAppenderBase<ILoggingEvent> {

    @Override
    protected void append(ILoggingEvent eventObject) {
        //no-op
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To add to ZachOfAllTrades' answer, here is a example `logback.xml` that sets the root log level to `INFO` but uses the `NOPAppender` to log everything to nirvana:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appender name="NOP" class="ch.qos.logback.core.helpers.NOPAppender"/>
  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="NOP"/>
  </root>
</configuration>
```